# Number of combinations in summation.

Tags: combinatorics

Supposing $i\in\{1,2,3,,\dots,m\}$, $r_i\in\{\beta_1,
\beta_2,\dots,\beta_r\}$ and $\alpha_{ij}\in\{0,1,2,3,\dots,\alpha\}$ how many distinct monomials $\sum_{j=1}^p\prod_{i=1}^mr_i^{\alpha_{ij}}$ contribute to this sum if $p$ is fixed?

Each vector $(\alpha_{1j},\alpha_{2j},\dots,\alpha_{mj})$ at a particular $j$ is distinct.

Is it $\binom{(r(\alpha+1))^m}{p}$?

Answer (score 1):

The monomials come from $\prod_{i=1}^mr_i^{\alpha_{ij}}$ at a given $j$.  Each $j$ can give you a different monomial.  There are $p$ choices of $j$.  There are many more possible monomials, but given your $r$'s and $\alpha$'s you get only one per value of $j$.

Comment: right how many possible sums are there?

Comment: That is quite a different question.  Please ask the question you are interested in.  Yes, assuming we don't have combinations of the variables that can make the monomials match, the number of possible sums is as you have said.